# Sub-menu not displaying correctly on hover

Tags: html, css

I have currently been working on a project and it's soon to be finished.
The main problem left which I have been scratching my head over is that the sub menus to the left of the "active menu" not showing up.

[Including a gif to display the problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErSOc.gif)

The URL of the website is: [www.su.fi](http://www.su.fi)

The problem I had before was that the sub-menu disappeared after hover, but that I solved by adding;

```css
.sub-nav, .sub-nav > ul {
 width: 500px !important;
 box-shadow: none;
 background-color: #FF008C;
 display: block;
}

#main-nav .act .sub-nav {
 visibility: visible !important;
 opacity: 1 !important;
```

After that I noticed that the menu items left to the active menu did not show up.

Best regards
Thanks!

Would be really happy if someone could give an input to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem i saw is that your

```
#main-nav .act .sub-nav {
    visibility: visible !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

its over the li:hover div.sub-nav layer.
A solution maybe play with the z-index:
On your li:over apply z-index: 999; to its children div.sub-nav

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Problem still persists after I've tried applying z-index to my "li:" elements as well as the sub-nav elements.

Comment: NVM my previous comment, solved it now! Thanks for the help!